# How do you keep the console code running if the IF statement is works?

Tags: c#, if-statement, request, response

I just wanna know how to make my code keep still going to run the other request if this IF statement is true.

```
if (response.Contains("token"))
{
      //some code to keep the program going... vv
}
```

Comment: couldn't get your question.

Comment: you can use continue or use recursive function.

Comment: You may want to search for _Thread_, _Task_ and _Parallel programming_

Comment: Not enough context. What "other request"? Do you already have multiple Threads running? ... Please have a look into [ask] , take the [tour] and if you could add a [mcve], that would be awesome.

Comment: You need to work a bit more on this question, if English is a problem for you, ask a friend to help you, as it stands this question is unclear